# Write to multiple Cells of a DataGridView in the same column at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to write on all cells at the same time when introducing data on the first cell of one column?
For example if I put `1` in the `Data` Column, auto-fill every cell on this Column.

An example in these images:

[image: Image11]   [image: Image22]

I have tried working with events:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
 {
     // [...}
    else if (titletext2.Equals("Data"))
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following codes

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Data") && e.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            string newValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
```